# Angular way to toggle a data-targeted submenu on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use an ng-click function to get the data-target attribute of a clicked target angular material md-button, so that when a topic is clicked in the sidenav, the submenu for it appears.

I've structured the navigation using md-list with md-items as I've seen suggested, but can't figure out a way to get this behaviour, especially with the .sidenav-submenu elements not being direct children of the md-button that's clicked on.

Not sure this would even be the best approach for achieving something like this, but I'm limited by angular material's lack of toggled sidenav submenu directive.

HTML:

```
<md-item>

  <md-button id="sidenav-paymentsButton" data-ng-click="toggleSubmenu($event)" data-target="#paymentsSubmenu">

    <md-content class="sidenav-link" md-ink-ripple="#3a455f" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">

      <div layout="row" layout-align="start center"><span class="sidenav-link-icon material-icons">money_off</span>

        Payments

      </div>

    <div><span class="expandSubmenu material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</span></div>

  </md-content>

</md-button>

<md-list id="paymentsSubmenu" class="sidenav-submenu">

  <md-item>

    <md-button ui-sref="newPayment">

      <md-content class="sidenav-link" md-ink-ripple="#3a455f" layout="row" layout-align="start center">

        <span class="sidenav-link-icon material-icons">create</span>

        New Payment

      </md-content>

    </md-button>

  </md-item>
```

navController JS:

```
app.controller('navController', function($scope, $state, $document) {

  angular.element('.sidenav-submenu').hide();

  $scope.toggleSubmenu = function($event) {
    var target = $event.target;
    // Not sure what to do next
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation in your controller. You use directives for DOM manipulation. That being said, what you want doesn't require any sort of custom directive that is not already built into angularjs.

Consider the following unstyled markup:

```
<div data-ng-click="nav.selected = 'A'">
  Your toggle for the "A" side nav.
</div>
<div data-ng-click="nav.selected= 'B'">
  Your toggle for the "B" side nav.
</div>


<div ng-if="nav.selected === 'A'>
  The "A" side nav.
</div>
<div ng-if="nav.selected === 'B'>
  The "B" side nav.
</div>
```

Used in conjunction with the following controller:

```
app.controller('navController', function($scope) {
  $scope.nav = {
    selected: 'A'
  };
});
```

You technically don't even need the controller for this example if you change the markup slightly, but it will be helpful in getting around the "dot problem" in case it pops up when moving this to your own example.

Comment: Kind of sent me in the right direction, although ended up using a 'condition = !=condition' ng-click action to toggle showing the submenu as the above didn't toggle, it just showed the submenu once without the toggle off

Comment: No problem... that is when you would upvote or mark as answer.